# About Prop 1.1 of "...Petri's Analysis..." by Stöhr & Viana

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading this [paper](http://gdz-lucene.tc.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gcs/gcs?&action=pdf&metsFile=PPN365956996_0061&divID=LOG_0020&pagesize=original&pdfTitlePage=http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/pdftitle/?metsFile=PPN365956996_0061%7C&targetFileName=PPN365956996_0061_LOG_0020.pdf&) and the authors Karl-Otto Stöhr and Paulo Viana define $\Omega^n$ to be the set of the sum of the monomios $\omega_1\cdots\omega_n$, where $\omega_i\in \Omega$ and $\Omega^n(D)$ to be the elements $\omega$ of $\Omega^n$ such that $div(\omega)\ge D$.

I didn't understand why $\frac{\lambda}{\mu_2}$ is well-defined, i.e., why $\frac{\lambda}{\mu_2}$ is a $(n-2)$-fold differential $(\frac{\lambda}{\mu_2}\in \Omega^{n-2})$.

In order to prove this I think we have to show that $\lambda$ is a multiple of $\mu_2$ so that we can cancel it.

[image]

It seems this fact is well-known to the specialists.

Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, it's just linear algebra.  Because you're looking in the kernel, you have $\lambda\mu_1+\eta\mu_2=0$, which can be solved to $\lambda\mu_1=-\eta\mu_2$, and then the question is about $\mu_2$ dividing $\lambda$ and $\mu_1$ dividing $\eta$.  Well, $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are linearly independent differentials, so they don't divide each other and are prime in the ring of monomials in the differentials.  Thus, $\mu_1|\eta\mu_2$ implies that $\mu_1|\eta$ and similarly $\mu_2|\lambda$.

Comment: I didn't understand, $\Omega^n$ is a vectorial space over a base field $k$, then we have the implication $\mu_1|\eta\mu_2\implies \mu_1|\eta$ if $\eta\in k$ which is not the case. What do you think? thank you!

Comment: The direct sum of the $\Omega^n$ form a polynomial ring with the linear part just the differential forms.  Remember to view $\eta$ as a polynomial in the $\omega_i$ and $\mu_i$ is a linear combination of the $\omega_i$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still having problems to understand it. For me since $\Omega^n$ is a vectorial space over $k$, the linear part should be $k$, no?

Comment: First off, a vector space is linear, there's not a "linear part" in this way.  The "linear part" I meant was of the ring $\oplus_n \Omega^n$ which is isomorphic to $k[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$, which is where the division is happening.